# Select box option to change input element ID

Tags: jquery

Following on from a question I posted yesterday. Found here: [Append different div id to option selects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372382/append-different-div-id-to-option-selects)

This is working Great ..

I just need to add one extra tweak, and I pretty much have it working how I need it.

Synopsis.

User picks option from select menu.
That option, triggers a div ID.

I also need it to change input ID aswell .

Is this dooable ?

Typical jQuery I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#selectanimage").change(function(){
$("#masterPreview > div").hide();
$("#" + $(this).val()).show();
});
});
```

The  select is :

```
<select id="selectanimage" name="selectanimage" style="width: 474px;" class="required">
<option value="null">--- Select your Image ... ---</option>
<option value="oneblk">125px x 125px Black Background</option>
</select>
```

The DIV this triggers is:

```
<div id="masterPreview">
<div id="oneblk">Apple Div</div>
</div>
```

However I also have an input element whos ID I want to simultaneously change based on select option chosen.

Its just a regular input element.

Any suggestions please ( incidentally the inputs ID ) will vary dependant on option select and it must be a different ID from that within the option select ( for css reasons )

EDIT----------------------------------

Fiddle here: >> http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/d5s9T/

Basically ( only coded for the first select ) but you should get the idea.

If they select the first option, I need the input id to become oneblkinput )

If they chose second select option I need input id to become onewhtinput

Etc

Comment: How do you plan to identify the input i.e. is there a unique class on that input? As I posted in the answer, ID of the input can't be used to identify the input as that would change per your requirement.

Comment: I have created FIDDLE here >> http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/d5s9T/ Will update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a way to "select" the input...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectanimage").change(function(){
        $("#masterPreview > div").hide();
        $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
        // The below line would update the ID of the element
        $("input.add_my_text").attr("id", $(this).val() + "input");
    });
});
```

Keep in mind, you can't use $("#inputID") as that ID would change.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5s9T/2/)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5s9T/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#selectanimage").change(function(){
      $("#masterPreview > div").hide();
      $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
      $(".add_my_text").attr('id',$(this).val());
   });
});
```

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand what you are suggesting. Could you please expand on this ?

Comment: Ok User picks a select option. This changes the div id , I also need it to change the id of an input element. So if user selects option with value of oneblk the div masterpreview displays within it div id oneblk. Simultaneously, I need input element to change its ID based on the select option chosen. So another input element on the page will now have ID = oneblkinput etc..

Answer (score 1):

well you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#selectanimage").change(function(){
$("#masterPreview > div").hide();
$("#" + $(this).val()).show();
$("#currentInputID").attr("id", "NewIDName");
});
});
```

but I don't think changing Id would be a wise option. you can use a function that does different thing with the same input having the same name by considering the option seleceted.

Comment: $("#cuurentInputID") should not be used as the ID would change the first time the selection changes.

Comment: well it doesn't differ. before the first time selection is changed the id would be **cuurentInputID** and as the first change changes to the new ID that will be used next time as the currentID

Comment: Im not sure I get this. Basically if user picks oneblk ( which is an option within the select menu .. along with others all different ) I need oneblk id to change to a specific named id for the input element. So if oneblk is chosen, lets say input id becomes oneblkinput and if onewht is chosen, the input id becomes onewhtinput as the id

Comment: ok, this line that i have added to your code changes the id of input: **$("#currentInputID").attr("id", "NewIDName");**